# Excel totals across sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

I am trying to add sales of parts across 6 sheets in excel

each part has an individual SKU number

I need to find sales for that number across all 6 sheets and give the sku part name in summery sheet

I have tried many google searches but i cant get anything to work

I am an excel novice

The sheets are all as follows

| Product Name | Product SKU | Sales Units |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name 1 | 123456 | 10 |
| name 2 | 789456 | 25 |
| name 3 | 564782 | 40 |

sheet names are

1. jan 23
2. feb 23
3. march 23
4. april 23
5. may 23
6. june 23

i hope this makes sense and can be done easily

Thanks in advance for any help or links to any help

Comment: Have a look at sumifs()

Comment: I tried SumIf but cannot get it to find the matching sku numbers across all sheets as i said complete novice

I can only get that to work if i type the numbers individually but my sheets have over 10000 rows in them

Comment: So show what you have tried.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41751119/4961700

Comment: 10000 rows * 6 is small compared to the 1,000,000 row capacity. I suggest you create a summary sheet, with a column for month - either by copying and pasting, or by formulae - set up 20,000 rows or each of the 12 months (and overflow detectors at 19999 if you want a high level of robustness). Then you can analyse however you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Microsoft-365 then could try `FILTER()` with `VSTACK()`.

```
=SUM(FILTER(VSTACK('jan 23:june 23'!$C$2:$C$500),VSTACK('jan 23:june 23'!$B$2:$B$500)=B3))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming no Excel Constraints as per your tags. Then the following formula will work for your requirements.*

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `C3`

```
=SUM(
        TOCOL('Jan 23:Jun 23'!$D$3:$D$1000,1)*
      --(TOCOL('Jan 23:Jun 23'!$C$3:$C$1000,1)=B3))
```

---

Or,

```
=BYROW(B3:B5,LAMBDA(α,SUM(
 TOCOL('Jan 23:Jun 23'!$D$3:$D$1000,1)*
 --(TOCOL('Jan 23:Jun 23'!$C$3:$C$1000,1)=α))))
```

---

**Note:** <kbd>TOCOL( )</kbd>, with parameter `1` ignores the blanks.

---