# Sumif across multiple Sheets, except the SUMPRODUCT way is not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I have a list of Sheet names in A71:A99 and I need to Sum based on Account Codes. This formula is not working and returning REF errors.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&$A$71:$A$99&"'!C:C"),Consolidated!$B12,INDIRECT("'"&$A$71:$A$99&"'!A:A")))
```

[Picture of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFnsC.png)

Based on the picture where am I going wrong?

Comment: My bet, and there is no way for us to check this, is that there are cells in the "Sheet Name" range that, because of spelling errors or blanks, that do not have a corresponding sheet.   One bad cell will cause the whole formula to fail.  Try with a smaller group first that you have double and triple checked the spelling.

Comment: Look at this **[Example-Excel totals across sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76538347/8162520)** may be you get some reference which may help to use. Uses `TOCOL()` & `BYROW()`

Comment: @ScottCraner This was actually the issue, one sheet did not exist that was within the list that was being pulled.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this works for me:

This is the formula on the sheet where I want the list of sheets:

```
TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", FALSE,Firstsheet:Lastsheet!A1),","))
```

**Note Scott Craner's suggestion** for a better version:

```
TOCOL(Firstsheet:Lastsheet!A1,3)
```

This is the formula in cell A1 on each sheet, I have a sheet named Firstsheet and another Lastsheet so I have all the target sheets between those.

That way I can control the list as needed.

```
MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1),1)+1,50)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: @ScottCraner that's brilliant - have to investigate TOCOL() now :)

Comment: Also just an fyi, you can combine the TOCOL directly in the SUMIF(INDIRECT()) if desired.

Comment: @ScottCraner just as you gave it worked without sumif or indirect - will be updating a very important workbook...

Comment: That just returns the list, the OP wants to then do a 3D SUMIF on all the sheets not just return the sheet names.

Comment: @ScottCraner ahh, well if the list is working then the rest should follow - I have to get lists of courses from some 20 program sheets...

Comment: I do not doubt that this will fix the OP's root problem, but you may want to show the last step of using it in the SUMIF, and note that the reason theirs is failing is most like due to typos.  Just to make this answer more accurate to the problem.