# I want to collect specific cell in all sheets in my Excel file

Tags: excel

I have Excel file for my cafe. Each day I make a new sheet with date as sheet name. For example 2024-03-05. Each day sale is in P7 Cell. There is a sheet names 'Report' for sum up sales of different days. In this sheet I have a column for sheets name in order of the date(In column A start from A4). I want to automatically write the sale in front of each day (In column G start from G4). For example, in 2024-03-05 my income was $100. So, in front of this day cell I want to see $10. Sorry if understandings my explanation is hard. My English is not good and explaining is hard for me.

I tried formulas like: =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A4,INDIRECT("'"&A4&"'!A:P"),7,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP(A4,INDIRECT("'"&A4&"'!A:P"),7,FALSE))
**and **
=INDIRECT("'"&A5&"'!G7")
which are suggested by AI. They didn't work. I've also tried VB codes, but still no result.

Comment: plz provide your vba codes

Comment: Edit this to suit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78088810/4961700 Looking on here before posting is usually helpful.

Comment: Try `=IFERROR(INDIRECT("'"&TEXT(A4,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'!P7"),"")`.

Answer (score 0):

`INDIRECT()` work for me, only format the date to prevent calc it as value

here a sample sheet I test it.

[image: here a sample sheet i test it]